# How to give if condition for propercase and uppercase in sap crystal report

Tags: if-statement, printing, crystal-reports, boolean, formula

I am getting two values one is printing **Cash** and other is printing **CASH** in **sap crystal report**. Now, I want that wherever **Cash** is showing at that time value should be **false** while if **CASH** is printing then the value should show **true**. So, for that I added the formula but didnt work,

here is my formula,

```
if(ProperCase({TmpSalesBillInstallmentReport.PaymentType}) = true)
then {TmpSalesBillInstallmentReport.PaymentType}= '0'
else if(UpperCase({TmpSalesBillInstallmentReport.PaymentType}) = true)
{TmpSalesBillInstallmentReport.PaymentType} = '1'
```

This formula is not working, even getting error i.e. **A Boolean Is Required Here(indicating on the first line)**

I surfing in net but didnt get related question also.

Answer (score 0):

`IF {TmpSalesBillInstallmentReport.PaymentType} = "CASH" Then True ELSE False;`

Note: A Crystal formula cannot assign a value to a database field. The field value is Read Only!

`UpperCase()` function is not a test that returns true or false. It simply returns the text argument after converting it to all upper case.

Comment: I tried this condition but in this condition "CASH" and "Cash" going in same condition i.e. : True

Answer (score 0):

You might have a setting causing comparisons to be case insensitive.
See: http://www.plumblineconsulting.com/crystal-reports-and-case-sensitivity-of-database-records/

Comment: Where is this option available in sap crystal report?

Comment: under the File menu.